# Why is two nextFocus requests needed to advance focus

Tags: flutter, dart, focus, textfield

I have a series of `TextField`s organized with `Column` widgets generated with a builder. Each `TextField` is wrapped in a `Focus` so I can take action with `onKeyEvent`. A resulting structure could look something like this:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Focus(child: TextField()),
    Focus(child: TextField()),
    Focus(child: TextField()),
    Column(children: [
      Focus(child: TextField()),
      Focus(child: TextField()),
      Focus(child: TextField()),
    ],),
    Focus(child: TextField()),
    Column(children: [
      Focus(child: TextField()),
      Focus(child: TextField()),
      Focus(child: TextField()),
    ],),
  ],
);
```

Using the `onKeyEvent` on a focused `TextField`, I can call `node.nextFocus` which will correctly defocus the current `TextField` and *supposedly* go to the next widget. However, I can't tell where it goes after 1 call to `nextFocus`. It takes 2 calls to `nextFocus` for the next `TextField` to be put in focus. Where could that first call have gone, and how do I immediately direct the focus to the next `TextField`?

Thanks!

Comment: I would run in debug and check which one has focus after node.nextFocus call. Put break points where you think it should be, then where it could be. Or step through and check each. Us Flutter devs need to be using the debugger a lot more. Myself included.

Comment: This is a dynamically generated structure though... how would I put a breakpoint where I want?